# In which Li Yong-Rui systems does the 15% outfitting price reduction apply?

Tags: elite-dangerous

The Power Play stats screen for Li Yong-Rui lists the 15% outfitting price reduction under the heading "Control systems", so naturally I would assume that only control systems have this bonus.

On the other hand I have read somewhere the suggestion to go to the Diaguandri system for outfitting because that's a high tech system that stocks high-level parts. However, Diaguandri is merely an exploited system, not a control system.

So in which of Li Yong-Rui's systems does the outfitting reduction apply? Control systems? Exploited systems? What about the HQ system, Lembava?

Comment: I know that the actual situation differs from the official description, so this could be true. (But that is too vague to become an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traveled to Diaguandri (exploited system), Balante (control system) and Lembava (HQ system), and the cost to buy ships was the same everywhere. I didn't check whether the reduction was indeed 15%, but here are the numbers for the two ship types that I checked:

- Type 6 Transporter: 889'054 credits
- Asp Explorer: 5'661'981 credits

Answer (score 0):

The 15% discount applies to all CONTROLLED and EXPLOITED Li Yong-Rui systems. I found you are best filtering the high tech systems only. You will notice a massive variation on what is on offer here.
Word of note too: I observed all of the visited Li Yong-Rui systems to be HOSTILE towards me and I had a fair few interdictions from angry NPCs.